# AngularJS model value not updated when I use editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jhtmlarea

I am using Jhtmlarea and this is my directive:

```
test.directive('jhtml', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',            
            replace: false,
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                $(elem).htmlarea({
                    toolbar: [
                   ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
                   ["p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"],
                   ["link", "unlink"]]
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

and this is my code:

```
<textarea cols="48" rows="17" ng-model="emailDetails.message" jhtml></textarea>
```

I can correctly see my textarea turned into editor but when I type into editor my model is not updated. What am I missing? What changes should I implement in the above code?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must *manually* handle the changes using AngularJS's `$watch`.

Comment: use the $apply method to notice the changes in custom directive. I think this helps you

Comment: @chamu: could you please give me example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use [textAngular](http://ngmodules.org/modules/textAngular), it is very well documented. It can save Your time :).

On main [page](http://textangular.com/) You have example how to perform "update" after text change.

And on codepen [codepen](http://codepen.io/paulbhartzog/pen/Hpsjg) :)

Answer (score 1):

You must manually set up `watcher`.

Here is the code from my custom directive which I've customized for your code. Try something like this:

```
var model = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
    if(value) {
        $timeout(function() {
            // Update whatever you need
        });
    }
});
```

Place this code in your `link` function after your code.

**Also** don't forget to inject `$timeout` and `$parse` services.

**UPDATE**

You can attach an event listener to your editor and update the `model` regarding the changes.

Something like this:

```
...

link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
    $(elem).htmlarea({
        toolbar: [
        ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
        ["p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"],
        ["link", "unlink"]]
    });

    $(elem).on('change', function(e) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.model = $(elem).val();
        });
    });
}

...
```

**NOTE**: This code is **NOT** tested. I've just demonstrated the principle of the solution. I don't know actually which kind of events has your editor.

Comment: Thanks friend but it is other way round. I want to update my model when the text in the editor changes. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: thanks Karl but the event doesn't fire. I would gladly give you +1 once I can hit the event but the change event doesn't fire :(

Comment: @Jack I've noted in my answer that it's the demonstration of the principle (where and how you should handle that change and update the model).

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look on tinymce editor for angularJS.

Here is the **[link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce)**.